# how to delete a savedState when it's not in the backStack? navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation

Version used: 2.7.1

we can save the state of the destination via `saveState` on the `NavOptionsBuilder` even if the destination is not present in the back stack.

there is a method in the NavController Class called `clearBackStack` that deletes `saveState` of the given destination, but it should be in the BackStack.

how can I delete a `saveState` when the destination is not in the backStack?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303194381